# iOS - Break UIbutton text to next line

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, uibutton

I am trying to implement a view similar to facebook news feed. I need to display a text like "**USER_NAME** posted a video on **PAGE_NAME**" . page name needs to be an uibutton that goes to the pageview when the user clicks on it. so the problem here is, the page name text is not breaking into next line if it's too long to fit in one line. I have tried `NSLineBreakByWordWrapping` but it's not helping.

EDIT : NSLineBreakByWordWrapping and setting numberOfLines to 0, just breaks the text to bottom of the PAGE_NAME button itself. but i need it to go to the bottom of username's.

Refer the image here to know how I'm supposed to implement
[image]

Comment: Did you set number of lines to 0?. If text is dynamic you have to set number of lines to 0

Comment: cell.button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
cell.button.titleLabel.numberOfLines  = 0;
cell.button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter; 
[button setTitle: [dataarray objectForKey:@"page_name"] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: @Duke, add your updated code in question rather than in comments.

Comment: Check my question again. it's updated.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting numberOfLines to 0.

```
button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
```

Comment: Sorry i couldn't be clear at first.. please check my edited question.

Answer (score 0):

**check this :**

```
test.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
test.titleLabel.numberOfLines=0;
```

**if u want to set  fit the text to the button:**

```
 test.titleLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
```

**u can use following properties too:**

```
test.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
test.contentHorizontalAlignment =UIControlContentHorizontalAlignmentLeft;
```

Comment: Sorry i couldn't be clear at first.. please check my edited question.

Comment: can u provide ur code for page_name and user_name buttons. by seeing the code only  we can able to helps u ...

Comment: Sorry i didn't reply sooner. I have tried this (via code/IB). but it breaks the texts right below the PAGE_NAME itself. but i need to break and rest of the text to go below to the USER_name

Comment: u found solution